# Can no longer use sudo apt update. Running 20.04

Tags: apt, wine

Was trying to install wine but came across an error:

Running `lsb_release` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

```
vnc@CustomSite:/etc/apt$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Hit:2 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:3 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Ign:4 https://packages.sury.org/php hirsute InRelease
Hit:5 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:6 https://packages.sury.org/php hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2606:4700:3030::ac43:b696 443]
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu hirsute InRelease
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu hirsute Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://packages.sury.org/php hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/boost-latest/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/wine/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

`nano sources.list` gives:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb [trusted=yes] http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
```

Please help me past this error.

Thanks.

Neo

Comment: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ hirsute main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several issues here with third-party repositories with your Ubuntu 21.04.
To fix them:

1. Disable PPAs:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:boost-latest/ppa
   sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:jonathonf/wine
   ```
2. To disable *`https://packages.sury.org/php`* you have to locate its file using `grep -r packages.sury.org /etc/apt --include=*.list`.

   In your case run:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
   ```

   and place `#` at the line *`deb packages.sury.org/php hirsute main`*, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> for save, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to close.
3. Restore normal default repositories - place the following into `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

   ```
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main universe multiverse restricted
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main multiverse universe restricted
   deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-security main universe multiverse restricted
   ```

   replacing lines with *digitalocean*.
4. Run `sudo apt-get update` .
5. Install Wine from official repositories as it was planned by

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository universe
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri* # we remove winehq here
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt install wine64 wine32:i386
   ```

Comment: It shows sources.list.d is a directory

Comment: Should I delete both files in it?

Comment: No. What is the output of `grep -r packages.sury.org /etc/apt --include=*.list `  ?

Comment: Like this? grep -r packages.sury.org /etc/apt --include=*.list ? ? -. With the question mark and the dash sign?

Comment: You have to open Nano using `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list` and then place `#` at the line start, <Ctrl+O> for save, <Ctrl+x> to close. Then run `sudo apt-get update` .

Comment: Ok now what do I do?

Comment: After editing the file run `sudo apt-get update` and ensure that you do not have any errors.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126423/discussion-between-neo-and-n0rbert).

Comment: grep -r ^deb /etc/apt --include=*.list
 
Neo
Neo
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb [trusted=yes] mirrors.digitalocean.com/… hirsute universe main restricted
 
N0rbert
N0rbert
I would recommend to remove this line.
 
Neo
Neo
Ok I'll try it
 
N0rbert
N0rbert
15:30
And place the default instead.
 
Neo
Neo
what's the default?
 
N0rbert
N0rbert
I'm uploading them.
pastebin.com/nKwPhNxJ
 
Neo
Neo
Ok now what?
 
N0rbert
N0rbert
sudo apt-get update
 
Neo
Neo
ok done
 
N0rbert
N0rbert
15:34
sudo apt-get install wine32:i386 wine64